# When building next 13.2 app I get an error: location not found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm using next 13.2 with the app directory.

I have a page that looks like this:

```
"use client";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
...

export default function Approve() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const loggedUser = getLoggedUser();
  const [code, setCode] = useState("");

  /**
   * if the user is not logged in, redirect him to login page
   */
  if (!loggedUser) {
    return router.replace("/login");
  }
...
```

In dev mode it works fine, but when I build the app I get an error: location not found

thrown by this line: `return router.replace("/login");`

Not sure why this is happening since it's a client component

Comment: Is this a top-level page component?

Comment: @vighnesh153 yes it is

Comment: You should run that inside of useEffect because even if the component is not a server component, it is rendered the first time on the server and the hydration happens on the client side. Docs: https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/rendering/server-and-client-components#client-components